# Gnuplot Eps file axis cut

Tags: border, gnuplot, cut

When I use gnuplot for some eps files I can get the some axis labels. That works. When I want to implement them into my latex document the axis discription gets cut away at the borders of the figure. It doesnt matter how large the figure is, the label letters gets cut away at the borders anyway.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you produce some minimal code that we can use to reproduce the problem?  e.g. make a plot with `sin(x)` and a label or 2 which get cut off.  Then show us how you include it in the latex document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot doesn't usually size .eps files perfectly, especially if there is something going on at the margins.  Thanks to [this post](http://agendafisica.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/fix-bounding-box-of-postscript-files-generated-by-gnuplot/) I learned that there is a simple command to correct the bounding box to adjust to the content of the .eps:

```
ps2epsi input.eps output.eps
```

This works fine for me.  There is also the [fixbb](http://www.gnuplot.info/scripts/files/fixbb) script on the gnuplot homepage.

Answer (score 0):

okay, here you go:

Latex Code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=1] {picture.eps}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:picture}
\end{figure}
```

Gnuplot

```
set terminal postscript enhanced portrait "Times Italic" 12 size 14cm,12cm                 #Key Character Size                           
set output 'picture.eps'
set multiplot layout 2,2

set border
set tics font "Times Italic, 10" 

set xlabel "{/Symbol e} %" font "Times Italic, 10" 
set ylabel "{/Symbol s}[MPa]" font "Times Italic, 10" rotate by -0

plot       plot exp(-x**2 / 2)
plot       plot exp(-x**2 / 2)
plot       plot exp(-x**2 / 2) 
plot       plot exp(-x**2 / 2)
```

something like this should work. Then the {/Symbol s}[MPa] isnt displayed properly in the latex document.

Comment: Thanks for posting the example code.  It would make more sense as an edit to your original question, though.